# My python program is not working properly, i'm not exactly sure why

Tags: python, primes

Firstly, I'm a beginner and I don't speak English very well, so any questions about what I'm trying to say are welcome. I was making a python program that received two numbers, and the program showed the prime numbers between them.

The algorithm takes the numbers, turns them into a list, then divides each number in that list by each of its predecessors. Then each integer division is passed to another list to see which of the numbers passed to the other list are primes.

Once passed to the second list, the prime numbers are those that are not repeated in that list, that is, when removing all the repeated values, I have a list of primes, but in some values ​​the function simply does not work. I would like to understand why. Thanks in advance!

Follow the code below:

```py
def Find_Primes(smaller_num, bigger_num):
    array = list(range(smaller_num, (bigger_num + 1)))
    array2 = []

    for i in array:
        for j in range(1, i):
            if i % j == 0:
                array2.append(i)
            
    for num in array2:
        if array2.count(num) > 1:
            while num in arrayt2:
                arrayt2.remove(num)

    print(array2)

smaller_number = int(input('Text the smaller number of interval: '))
bigger_number = int(input('Text the other number of interval: '))
Find_Primes(smaller_number, bigger_number)
```

Comment: "in some values the function simply does not work".  Please provide inputs that work and don't work and actual vs. desired outputs.

Comment: Also make sure your code is accurate.  This code has `arrayt2` in two places and it isn't defined (and probably a typo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def find_primes(smaller_num, bigger_num):
    # empty list to hold list of prime numbers
    lst_of_primes = []
    # loop to go through numbers in the range
    for number in range(smaller_num, bigger_num):
        # variable to hold the count of factors
        factors = 0
        # loop to test possible factors for the number
        for test_num in range(2, number):
            # if integer division leaves no remainder
            if number % test_num == 0:
                # increment factors variable
                factors += 1
        # number has no factors
        if factors  == 0:
            # add it to the list of prime numbers
            lst_of_primes.append(number)
    # output the final list
    print(lst_of_primes)

    smaller_number = int(input('Enter the smaller number of interval: '))
    bigger_number = int(input('Enter the larger number of interval: '))
    find_primes(smaller_number, bigger_number)
```

Comment: i still don't understood why my answer don't work, but this solve is definitely most elegant, thank you for the help!!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your are adding `i` multplied by `j` numbers to array2 instead if (probably?) `j` numbers. Look at the output.

```
def Find_Primes(smaller_num, bigger_num):
    array = list(range(smaller_num, (bigger_num + 1)))
    array2 = []


    for i in array:
        #numbers from input
        for j in range(1, i):
            if i % j == 0:
                array2.append(i)
    print(array2)
    print("\n")
        
    for num in array2:
        if array2.count(num) > 1:
            while num in array2:
                array2.remove(num)

    print(array2)

smaller_number = 1
bigger_number = 15
Find_Primes(smaller_number, bigger_number)
```

**output:**

```
[2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15]


[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 15, 15, 15]
```

Comment: Yes, look the second output, apart from 15, every numbers in list are primes, but, i don't know why, the 15 is repeating.

Comment: you are adding j multiplied by i times to the list everytime i is not a prime number.

Comment: I correct myself:
you are adding (number of not coprime numbers till j +1) times to array2.
Noncoprimes of 4 is 2.
Noncoprimes of 12 are 2,3,4,6
Noncoprimes of 15 are 5 and 3.

Number of non coprimes of 4 = 1  -> appending (1+1)* i  times to array2.
Number of non copromes of 12  = 4 -> appending (4+1)*i times to array2.
Number of non coprimes until 15 = 2 -> appening (2+1* i times to array2)